# PlayOnLinux Adobe Air requires a version that is not available

Tags: wine, playonlinux, adobe

Can anyone help me.
I am trying to run League of Legends with PlayOnLinux, but whenever I try to click Launch button, the message just pops up:
This app requires a version of Adobe Air which cannot be found!
Get the new version on adobe.com/go/getair

Even when I go to tha site and download the Air installer it says the same thing.
Guys help me, I really wanna play League of Legends!

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the question  title.

Comment: Okay, sorry for doing that... I didnt know.

Answer (score 2):

Did some digging and it seems to be a problem with the package `liblcms2` . For more information see here: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-3015.html .

Try installing the 32-bit version of `liblcms2` with:

```
sudo apt-get install liblcms2-2:i386
```

And then installing Adobe Air through Playonlinux.
Let me know how it works out!

Comment: Your method didnt seem to fix my problem, but thanks for the help anyway. The solution is in the answer that has a green checkmark next to it! (or the one that starts with "The answer by OP"

Comment: @Elderzz Good for you :) By the way; it still doesn't have a green check mark though

Answer (score 1):

The answer by OP.

I fixed this by clicking the "Configure" button on PlayOnLinux,
clicking on "Wine" tab and clicking "Configure Wine".

In the "Wine configuration window, click on the "Libraries" tab
and where it says "New override for library: " type "dnsapi"
(without the quotes), and click "Add" button!

Hopefully this helps some people
I also installed .NET 4.5! So try that out aswell!